# Is trigonometry part of synthetic approach to geometry?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry

I used to think Trigonometry is an analytic way to solve math problems but now I'm reading a book with only synthetic methods to solve geometry problems and it contains trigonometry too.
I can't understand the difference between analytic  and synthetic approaches to geometry.

Comment: Apparently for this author, trigonometry is included in the author's interpretation of "synthetic", but presumably, a solution using coordinates would be "analytic". Author's choice.

Comment: @quasi-for you what is the difference between synthetic and analytic. Can you please write an answer explaining it not just a comment

Comment: I usually think of synthetic as using only concepts of geometry that don't require trigonometry or coordinates, but as I said, it's author's choice. Go with the flow.

Comment: OK. I thought of solving all my question with synthetic approaches and now wondering whether I should use trigonometry or not.What is your opinion?

Comment: I don't have time to write answer (maybe someone else will), but the bottom line is that some terminology is not cast in stone, and for those terms, as long as the meaning is clear in a given context, then there's no issue.

Comment: @quasi-Ok thanks

Comment: Analysis and synthesis are two sides a coin made in any mathematical process. Analysis looks at the bits and has no value unless integrated together as a whole... connecting to the senses .

Comment: Trigonometry was well known well before the advent of coordinates geometry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry#History

Comment: what is the book you are reading?

Comment: @estragon-A beautiful journey through olympiad geometry.

Answer (score 0):

*"I can't understand the difference between analytic and synthetic approaches to geometry."*

I think a good way to understand the difference between the two is that in *analytic geometry*, mathematicians assign a a real number to each pair of points in whatever space they are working in (representing the distance between the given points).  Similarly for angle measure. When one assigns real numbers to represent things like angle and distance one has entered the realm of analytic geometry.

So, while precise definitions change from century to century (and even author to author in the same century), in *synthetic* geometry, we might claim that two angles are *congruent*, meaning one could be superimposed on the other with no mention of a numerical quantity.  In *analytic* geometry we might claim that two angles are *equal* meaning that the numbers used to measure those angle are the same.

Again, the precise meanings of particular words can vary depending on the setting, but the use of real numbers to describe geometric entities is the hallmark of the analytic approach.

Comment: happy to discuss the down vote ...

Comment: @estragon- So what about trigonometry?

Comment: In Book II of  _The Elements_, for example,  Euclid had synthetic results that are equivalent to the Law of Cosines.  The Greeks knew their way around a right triangle, but the arguments Euclid made were synthetic in nature: no coordinates, no use of the idea of number to characterize length, area, or angle.

Comment: As far as synthetic/analytic goes, compare Hilbert's axioms for Euclidean geometry with Birkhof's axioms.  Wallace and West's book _Roads to Geometry_ has a discussion regarding that.  Van Brummelen has a book _The Mathematics of the Heavens and the Earth: The Early History of Trigonometry_ which I have just picked up. Might be worth a look as well.

Comment: Ok I will see them. Never read one of them. I just had to prove a question related to area and I used trigonometry there. Now I'm wondering whether it was an analytic proof or synthetic proof

Comment: Here is a quote directly from _Wallace and West:_ "The essence of analytic geometry is the use of the one-to-one correspondence between points on a line and the real numbers ... to establish a coordinate system for points in the plane."_ (1st edition, pg. 106; a brief conversation follows).

Comment: That means trigonometry is part of synthetic geometry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78003/discussion-between-estragon-and-love-invariants).